# How to answer questions from big documents?

Tags: nlp

About two weeks ago, due to the low demand in my project, I have been assigned a completely unusual request: to automatically extract answers from documents based on machine learning. I've never read anything about ML, AI or NLP before, so I've been basically doing just that for the past two weeks.

When it comes to ML, most book recommendations and tutorials I've found so far use the Python language and tools, so I took the first week to learn about Python, NumPy, Scikit, Panda, Matplotlib and so on. Then, this week I started reading about NLP itself, after spending a few days reading about generic ML algorithms.

So far, I've basically read about Bag of Words, using TF-IDF (or simply terms count) to convert the words to numeric representations and a few methods such as the gaussian and multinomial naive bayes methods to train and predict values. The methods also mention the importance of using the usual pre-processing methods such as lemmatization and alikes. However, basically all examples assume that a given text can be classified in one of the categorized topics, like the sentiment analysis use case. I'm afraid this doesn't represent my use case, so I'd like to describe it here so that you could help me identifying which methods I should be looking for.

We have a system with thousands of transactions/deals inputted manually by an specialized team. Each deal has a set of documents (a dozen per deal typically) and some documents could have hundreds of pages. The inputing team has to extract about a thousand fields from those documents for any particular deal. So, in our database we have all their data and we typically also know the document specific snippets associated to each field value.

So, my task is to, given a new document and deal, and based on the previous answers, fill in as many fields as I could by automatically finding the corresponding snippets in the new documents. I'm not sure how I should approach this problem.

For example, I could consider each sentence of the document as a separate document to be analyzed and compared to the snippets I already have for the matching data. However, I can't be sure whether some of those sentences would actually answer the question. For example, maybe there are 6 occurrences in the documents that would answer a particular question/field, but maybe the inputters only identified 2 or 3 of them.

Also, for any given sentence, it could tell that the answer for a given field is A or B, or it could be that there's absolutely no association between the sentence and the field/question, as it would be the case for most sentences. I know that Scikit provides the predict_proba method, so that I could try to only consider the sentence as relevant if the probabilities of answering the question would be above 80%, for example, but based on a few quick tests I've made with a few sentences and words, I suspect this won't work very well. Also, it could be quite slow to treat each sentence of a 500-hundreds of pages documents as a separate document to be analyzed, so I'm not sure if there are better methods to handle this use case.

Some of the fields are free-text ones, like company and firm names, for example, and I suspect those would be the hardest to answer, so I'm trying to start with the multiple-choice ones, with a finite set of classification.

How would you advise me to look at this problem? Are there any algorithms you'd recommend me to study for solving this particular problem?

Please forgive me for any imprecise/incorrect terms or understanding on this topic as this is all very new to me. Any help is very appreciated, thanks.

Update: I've been asked for more details, so here you are.

One of the fields is called "Deal Structure" and it could have the following values: "Asset Purchase", "Stock or Equity Purchase" or "Public Target Merger" (there are a few others, but this gives you an idea).

So, here are some sentences highlighted for Public Target Merger deals (those documents come from Edgar Filings public database which are freely available for US deals):

deal 1 / doc 1:
"AGREEMENT AND PLAN OF MERGER, dated as of March 14, 2018 (this “Agreement”), by and among HarborOne Bancorp, Inc., a Massachusetts corporation (“Buyer”), Massachusetts Acquisitions, LLC, a Maryland limited liability company of which Buyer is the sole member (“Merger LLC”), and Coastway Bancorp, Inc., a Maryland corporation (the “Company”)."

"WHEREAS, Buyer, Merger LLC, and the Company intend to effect a merger (the “Merger”) of Merger LLC with and into the Company in accordance with this Agreement and the Maryland General Corporation Law (the “MGCL”) and the Maryland Limited Liability Company Act, as amended (the “MLLCA”), with the Company to be the surviving entity in the Merger. The Merger will be followed immediately by a merger of the Company with and into Buyer (the “Upstream Merger”), with the Buyer to be the surviving entity in the Upstream Merger. It is intended that the Merger be mutually interdependent with and a condition precedent to the Upstream Merger and that the Upstream Merger shall, through the binding commitment evidenced by this Agreement, be effected immediately following the Effective Time (as defined below) without further approval, authorization or direction from or by any of the parties hereto; and"

deal 2 / doc 1:

"WHEREAS, it is also proposed that, as soon as practicable following the consummation of the Offer, the Parties wish to effect the acquisition of the Company by Parent through the merger of Purchaser with and into the Company, with the Company being the surviving entity (the “Merger”);"

Now, for Asset Purchase deals:

deal 3 / doc 1:

"Subject to the terms and conditions of this Agreement, Sellers are willing to sell to Buyer, and Buyer is willing to purchase from Sellers, all of their assets relating to the Businesses as set forth herein."

deal 4 / doc 1:

"WHEREAS, Seller wishes to sell and assign to Buyer, and Buyer wishes to purchase and assume from Seller, the rights and obligations of Seller to the Purchased Assets (as defined herein), subject to the terms and conditions set forth herein."

I hope those examples could help on defining the problem, please let me know in the comments and responses if you need more details.

Answer (score 2):

So first, you would probably want different models to fill in different fields. But I would recommend looking into word2vec or other embedding models.

A big question is on the type of fields you're trying to fill in - is it information thats simply verbatim/explicit in the text (like date for instance?) or is it things like decide the topic based on the words.

Another remark is that with 1000+ fields.. you're not going to finish the project for a lonnggg time (yrs scale) unless you're looking at relatively poor accuracy. Refining a model/testing various hyperparameters takes a while (typically hours, days if you're realllly using a complicated method or have poor resources like no GPUs for a Neural Net) for a single model.. and you'll want a model for each field realistically (unless its verbatum information).

Comment: Realistically, your question is too vague. You don't really have a specific idea of what problem you're trying to solve, and you're really asking about a ton of different problems.

Comment: The idea is that those deals filled in automatically are still going to be reviewed by the same team that currently inputs those deals. They take a long time filling in those fields manually, which makes this process expensive, so hopefully it should be much quicker for them to review the answers and fix them than to have to fill all of them fields themselves I guess. I've updated the description of the question to include some details.

Comment: thanks by the way for all information provided so far. Regarding word2vec, I believe this tool is used to build the Bag of Words or some w-shingling (n-grams) in a similar way the TF-IDF algorithm works. I'm more worried about the algorithm that I should use after vectorizing the words into some numeric representation, as I think this is the most critical part, right?

Comment: For alot of NLP models the input vectors and how you get them matter just as much as the algorithm you use to get an output based on them. On modelling you generally will want to test a bunch of models and compare them empirically rather than theoretically. 
Another important question - do you have labeled/correct data? Supervised algorithms are probably what you want, but they need data to train with, ie data where the correct answer is known (so like input vec [1, 0, 1] -> class 1, [2, 0, 2] -> 2, [0, 0, 1] -> 0, [1, 1, 1] -> 1 kinda thing).

Comment: ^And by labeled data, you'll need ideally a few thousand pieces of labeled data per class you're trying to distinguish between (if doing supervised, which is probably what you want).

Comment: Yes, the current labeled data is supposed to be correct as they have been inputted and reviewed by real humans. There are about a thousand deals in the database and the fields I'm seeking to start modeling are supposed to be filled in for all those deals, so hopefully I can successfully start with them but I still don't know what algorithm I should be looking for. What supervised algorithms would you recommend for this use case?

Answer (score 2):

This class of task in Natural Language Processing is known as Information Extraction. In particular, the task that you are doing is a bit like "scenario templates" or "slot filling". This is a bit different from usual slot filling because of your requirement to search in a specific document. The technique known as "distant supervision" is probably applicable since you do not know where each value in your database of "answers" is mentioned in a relevant reference in the document text.

Comment: thanks, that should help me researching more about those tasks and how to implement them.

Answer (score 1):

After our conversation it seems like the general process you want to do is the following: 
Convert your corpus to usable formats:

```
~Preprocess your corpus to remove stop words. Maybe use lemmatization. 
Consider using the [hashing trick][1] if worried about corpus size
Convert docs to vectors (TFIDF or BOW should be good for most of your cases)
```

Create & Train Models:

```
Basic models seem better for you if you're new - in simple classification use
Naive Bayes or decision forest or support vector machines (SVMs).
```

Basic code:

```
x_train, x_test = splitting(x, 0.8) #Ratio of train to test = 0.8, better to do crossvalidation
y_train, y_test = splitting(y, 0.8)
clf = SVC() #Or whatever algo
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
acc = clf.score(x_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm specifically worried about identifying the few relevant parts from the whole documents. The way you describe seems to work well when classifying movies reviews as good or bad, for example, since they are usually small docs with relevant information. But I'm afraid my use case would be rather different from the usual sentiment analysis one.

Answer (score 0):

I've also asked this question in the Python's Scikit-learn mailing list and I got an amazing response from Boris Hollas that mentioned an article tackling this exact problem with the HMM algorithm. The article is called "Information Extraction with HMM Structures Learned by Stochastic Optimization" by Dayne Freitag and Andrew McCallum. I still lack the required background to fully understand that article, but it certainly serves as a very good starting point towards better understand the problem and its possible solutions. Thanks a lot, Boris!!!

Like joeln pointed in his answer, this class of task is known as Information Extraction and he also mentioned that this task would be a bit like "scenario templates" or "slot filling" while the Wikipedia article on Information Extraction would call it "Template filling" if I understood it correctly. With all those variants it will certainly make it easier for me to continue my research after I know the commonly used terms for this particular task.

Thanks a lot to everyone that helped me with proceeding with my researches on this topic, specially Evan Mata, who encouraged me to provide some more concrete examples to help explaining the problem itself and for providing some initial estimate on how long such process could take to finish. This is all very useful since my client will also have the opportunity to decide on whether it worths keep investing time and money on this task.